# How to handle multiple HttpMessageNotReadableException's that comes from a single RequestBody?

Tags: java, api, exception, error-handling, spring-restcontroller

For the following REST call,

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/speedCalculation", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> processSpeedRequest(@RequestBody SpeedRequest speedRequest) {
```

the following is my POST request body.
"speed" is of type **enum** & "startDate" is of type **LocalDate**

```
"details": {
                "speed": "FAST",
                "startDate": "2020-01-01"
            },
```

If my request is given an invalid enum value and invalid date format, i'm able to handle only **one** **HttpMessageNotReadableException**, since only one is thrown at a time. (It actually throws whatever is encountered first).In this case, i'm only able to handle only "speed".

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleMessageNotReadableException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        // some handling
        return new ResponseEntity<>("invalid request------", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

I would like to catch both the errors(two of the HttpMessageNotReadableException's) of the request body and then give error response including both the fields.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since validator won't work in your case, you could use the @JsonCreator on the constructor and do your validation in there. Then throw the exception from there if your validation doesn't pass. For example your request object would look something like the following:

```
public class SpeedRequest {

private final SpeedEnum speed;
private final LocalDate date;

@JsonCreator
public SpeedRequest(@JsonProperty("speed") String speed, @JsonProperty("date") String date) {
    //Validate fields and throw exception if needed or cast and assign
}

// Methods
```

}

Comment: I just checked what you're saying. But the ValidationUtils are only checking EmptyOrWhitespace. My case here is What if you provide invalid enum value and invalid date format. I don't see the Validator handling my scenario.

Comment: Did that fix the issue for you @techDoubts23?

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks in Advance @heyo